# Docker - Docker is Complaining When Using $PWD: In Windows 10 Pro

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am learning docker right now and just trying to follow along with their tutorial. I am already in the topic of **Using Bind Mounts** and I encountered an issue that  I can't seem to find a solution. I tried executing the following command just like what's in the tutorial,

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 \ -w /app -v $PWD:/app \ node:12-alpine \ sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```

..but it keeps on throwing the following error message,

> At line:1 char:39
>   + docker run -dp 3000:3000 \ -w /app -v $PWD:/app \ node:12-alpine \ sh ...
>   +                                       ~~~~~
>   Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive

I already tried using the following solutions,

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 \ -w /app -v ${PWD}:/app \ node:12-alpine \ sh -c "yarn install && run dev"
docker run -dp 3000:3000 \ -w /app -v "${PWD}:/app" \ node:12-alpine \ sh -c "yarn install && run dev"
docker run -dp 3000:3000 \ -w /app -v "${PWD}":/app \ node:12-alpine \ sh -c "yarn install && run dev"
docker run -dp 3000:3000 \ -w /app -v ${pwd}:/app \ node:12-alpine \ sh -c "yarn install && run dev"
docker run -dp 3000:3000 \ -w /app -v "${pwd}:/app" \ node:12-alpine \ sh -c "yarn install && run dev"
docker run -dp 3000:3000 \ -w /app -v "${pwd}":/app \ node:12-alpine \ sh -c "yarn install && run dev"
```

...but to no avail and I am just seeing this error,

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.
>   See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

I'll appreciate it if someone could help and guide me resolve this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below command.

```
$ docker run -dp 3000:3000 -w /app -v ${PWD}:/app  node:12-alpine  sh -c "yarn install && run dev"
```

You have to remove the `\` as you have written the command in one line.

`\` is most commonly used in situations like these (i.e. to make it easier to read a long command):

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 \
-w /app -v $PWD:/app \
node:12-alpine \
sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```